# Double integral with two variables in the exponential: $\int_0^\pi \int_0^\infty e^{-ibx\cos\theta - {x/a}} x^2 \sin\theta ~dx~d\theta $.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, substitution

I'm having trouble with the substitutions in the following integral:

> $$\int_0^\pi \int_0^\infty  e^{-ibx\cos\theta - {x/a}} x^2 \sin\theta ~dx~d\theta $$

**My attempt:**

Let $$u = \cos\theta$$ then $$ du = -\sin\theta~d\theta$$

Then we have

$$-1 \int_0^\pi \int_0^\infty  e^{-ibxu - {x/a}} x^2 ~du~dx $$

How do I separate the u out of the exponential to integrate separately with respect to $u$ and then $x$? Am I doing the wrong substitution?

Comment: Seems you forgot to change the bounds after the substitution.

Comment: When you change variables, you have to change the endpoints to match: $\theta = 0$ corresponds to $u = \cos \theta = 1$, $\theta = \pi$ to $u = -1$.

Comment: ... and then you can do the $du$ integral, treating $x$ as constant.

Comment: Why do we treat x as constant?

Comment: @Ella As $u$ changes, $\theta$ changes, but does $x$ change?

Comment: Okay I see, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int_0^\pi \int_0^\infty  e^{-ibx\cos\theta - \frac1ax} x^2 \sin\theta ~dx~d\theta
&= \int_{-1}^1\int_0^\infty  e^{-ibxu - \frac{x}{a}} x^2 ~dx ~du \\
&= \int_0^\infty\left(\int_{-1}^1  e^{-ibxu - \frac{x}{a}} x^2 ~du\right) ~du \\
&= \int_0^\infty x^2e^{-\frac{x}{a}}\left(\dfrac{e^{-ibx}}{ibx} - \dfrac{e^{-ibx}}{ibx}\right) ~du \\
&= \dfrac{2}{b}\int_0^\infty xe^{-\frac1ax}\sin bx dx \\
&= \dfrac{2}{b}{\cal L}(x\sin bx)\Big|_{s=\frac1a}  \\
&= \dfrac{2}{b}\dfrac{2\frac1a~b}{(\frac{1}{a^2}+b^2)^2} \\
&= \dfrac{4a^3}{(1+a^2b^2)^2}
\end{align}